# "Error when Importing 'mysdk' into iOS Demo App: dyld Library not loaded: @rpath/MQTTClient.framework/MQTTClient"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk, salesforce-ios-sdk

When integrating "mysdk" into an iOS demo application and utilizing a third-party library, encountering an error where the MQTTClient.framework fails to load. Despite "mysdk" functioning correctly in isolation, importing it into the demo app results in the error message: "dyld Library not loaded: @rpath/MQTTClient.framework/MQTTClient". This issue disrupts the successful integration of "mysdk" into the demo application, impacting its functionality and performance. A solution is sought to rectify this error while ensuring seamless integration of "mysdk" with the third-party library into the iOS demo application.

To resolve the "dyld Library not loaded" error when integrating "mysdk" into your iOS demo application, ensure that the MQTTClient.framework is correctly added to the project, configured in the framework search paths, and properly signed. Clean and rebuild the project, verify compatibility with the deployment target, and check for any dependency conflicts. Updating or reinstalling the MQTTClient.framework may also help resolve the issue.